# Update Query using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to build an update query - For example

```
update table A set Column 1 = ,Column 2= , Column 3..... where 
Constant selection criteria
```

Lets says max number of columns that is to be updated is 3 and there can be any set of combination depending upon some business rule , For example

```
Condition 1 - update only Column 1
Condition 2 - update Column 1 and Column 2 and so on. ( 6 combinations in this case)
```

How would your approach be , to build update Query in this case ?

I am NOT using Hibernate .

I can think of crude way to build queries only.

Comment: Do you have the original row at your disposal when doing the update?

Comment: @heikkim I would have that

Answer (score 0):

You could query the original row, make changes to values that need changing and then update all the column values - regardless of what's actually changed. This of course creates some unnecessary overhead but if execution time / processing power is not critical, then the overhead can be accepted.

Comment: Well i thought of this ..lets see if somebody can come with any other approach

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using simple SQL query like below:-

```
String query ="update table_name set col=something,col2=something where col3=?";
jdbcTemplate.update(query, yourParam);
```